# error in grouping by year,month in mysql

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have this code, and it is working properly on the online server:

```
SELECT
DATE(`order`.`date`) AS `dater`,
COUNT(*) AS `orders-amount`,
SUM(`order`.`price`) AS `orders-income`,
(SELECT SUM(`amount`) FROM `paypal` WHERE `paypal`.`txn_id` != 'Bonus' AND YEAR(`dater`) = YEAR(`paypal`.`posted_date`) AND MONTH(`dater`) = MONTH(`paypal`.`posted_date`)) AS `total_charge`
FROM `order`
GROUP BY YEAR(`dater`), MONTH(`dater`)
ORDER BY `dater` DESC
```

But on localhost it gives an error as below:

```
#1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'panel.order.date' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

Id I used this code for grouping then it working properly:

```
GROUP BY `dater`
```

This error appear only on localhost as I'm running on linux Mint and installing the apache, php, mysql & pypmyadmin

Comment: Something a little off there -- if it's working in production, then it's because it's returning an arbitrary date for that year and month.  Generally speaking, if you want to group by year and month, then you should be selecting those fields instead of the date.  If you want to group by the date, then your 2nd example is correct.  A little difficult to say without sample data and expected results.

Comment: MySQL 5.7 by default enforces `only_full_group_by` which makes MySQL behave more like standard SQL, and like almost every other RDBMS implementation. You can either change your `sql_mode` or else you can write your queries to conform to the requires semantics.

Comment: @sgeddes Thanks for your reply, I make some thing like this but it is not working too, I tried many times but I cannot understand this error, also why it is working without errors on the server, just wondering

Comment: Your localhost has `only_full_group_by` enabled, probably because it is a newer version of MySQL.  You must add `total_charge` to the `GROUP BY`, but doing so may change the outcome of your query.  This is a mistake MySQL developers have made for years because of its lenient behavior in earlier versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it in your error message:

> this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

If you did not set it on purpose, I guess you got it by default and you have a different version on your local server (see [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/quick-tip-how-to-permanently-change-sql-mode-in-mysql/), it was made default at some point).

So all you need is to disable this mode, either by running `SET sql_mode='';`, or by following instructions [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/quick-tip-how-to-permanently-change-sql-mode-in-mysql/)

Comment: Thank you very much, I follow the instructions in the link you send and changing the mode and it is working properly right now :)

Answer (score 3):

It means that different sql modes are used on local and remote servers.
Either you should change the mode or update your query like:

```
SELECT
YEAR(ANY_VALUE(`order`.`date`)) date_year,
MONTH(ANY_VALUE(`order`.`date`)) date_month,
COUNT(*) AS `orders-amount`,
SUM(`order`.`price`) AS `orders-income`,
(SELECT SUM(`amount`) FROM `paypal` WHERE `paypal`.`txn_id` != 'Bonus' AND YEAR(ANY_VALUE(`order`.`date`)) = YEAR(`paypal`.`posted_date`) AND MONTH(ANY_VALUE(`order`.`date`)) = MONTH(`paypal`.`posted_date`)) AS `total_charge`
FROM `order`
GROUP BY date_year, date_month
```